# jquery alert confirmation prior to changing page

Tags: jquery, redirect, alert

In jscript i was able to pop an alert message and redirect as follows:

```
alert('" & message & "'); window.location.href = '" & redirectPage & "';"
```

This would pop a message, await the user's acknowledgement and then redirect to a new page.

I'm now using the nice jquery UI:

```
$.alert(""" & message & """, """ & title & """);
```

When i include the `window.location.href` forward to a new address the user no longer has a chance to acknowledge the information box. (it appears and disappears)

is there a way to ensure the user clicks the ok in the jquery alert?

Comment: You can use [window.onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload) - But al least on chrome you can't set a custom message due to security restrictions

Answer (score 0):

Added the close function into the routine

```js
$.extend({
    alert: function (message, title, redirect) {
        $("<div></div>").dialog({
            buttons: { "Ok": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
            close: function (event, ui) { $(this).remove(); },
            resizable: false,
            title: title,
            modal: true,
            close: function (event, ui)
            {
                if (redirect != '')
                {
                    window.location.href = "default.aspx";
                }
            }
        }).text(message);

    }
});
```